# Poner un enlace dentro de un canvas

Tags: php, javascript, canvas

con PHP y a través de una consulta de SQL, obtengo unos parámetros, que los muestro a través de un for y que acaban mostrándose como un enlace. Esto es fácil de implementar y funciona, pero quiero que ese enlace este dentro de un canvas de HTML y aquí es donde me aparecen los problemas, porque, si meto el enlace en una variable PHP y esta luego la paso a una variable Javascript que luego meto en el canvas como texto, lo que me hace es mostrarme el enlace como texto con todo el código HTML. Digo yo que debe haber una manera más sencilla de hacerlo.

Algo como lo que pongo a continuación:

```js
function crearcanvas(enlace) {
  var link = enlace;
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.fillStyle = '#CCCC00'; 
 canvas.font = "sans-serif";
 canvas.fillStyle = "black";
 canvas.fillText(enlace,45,75);
  ....
  ....
}
```

```html
<php
  $tabla = tabla();
    foreach ($db->query($tabla) as $row) { 
      $valor1 = $row['valor1'];
      $valor2 = $row['valor2'];
      $valor3 = $row['valor3'];
      $enlace = "<a href='pagina.php?valor1=".$valor1."&valor2=".$valor2."'>".$valor3."</a>";
?>
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      <script>
        var enlace = <?php echo $enlace; ?>;
        crearcanvas(enlace);
      </script>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Una cosa, no estoy buscando crear un botón o una animación, solo quiero poner un simple enlace dentro del canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poner un enlace en un canvas, tienes que dibujarlo tú mismo y responder al evento click.

Es más sencillo solapar un div por encima:

```html
<div style='position: relative;'>
     <canvas id="canvas" width="l00" height="100" style="position: absolute; left:0; border: 1px solid black;">Canvas no soportado.</canvas>
     <div style='position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 5px;'><a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>Enlace</a> </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Gracias, sabia que tenía que ser más sencillo.